# Java Locale LanguageRange priority list: how to list en-US-POSIX after en-US?

Tags: java, locale

Java Locale LanguageRange: how to list en-US-POSIX after en-US?

```
    List<LanguageRange> ranges = LanguageRange.parse("en-US;q=1.0,en-US-POSIX;q=0.9");

    List<Locale> locales = Locale.filter(ranges,
            Arrays.asList(Locale.getAvailableLocales()));
```

The result is en-US-POSIX, en-US.

The order expected is en-US, en-US-POSIX.

java 11.

Comment: I think the issue stems from the fact that `en_US_POSIX` is an acceptable tag to return for a request of just `en-US`. Try removing the `-POSIX` input and you'll see that both will be returned. If you want your inputs to be considered the *most specific* tag to match (i.e. only `en-us-posix` should match itself, but `en-us` should only match `en-us`), then you need to use the lookup functions instead. `Locale.lookup(ranges, allLocales)` will return `en_US` with your input.

Comment: Thanks. The weight 1.0 is not honored.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm telling you: `en-US;q=1.0` **is** honored. It just so happens that this specific request will match **both** `en-US` and `en-US-POSIX`. Try requesting **just** `en-US;q=1.0` and you'll observe that you get the same response back.

Comment: en-US-POSIX has weight 0.9. It is explicitly listed, and should be honored.

Comment: I don't know how many more ways to tell you this: If the request of `en-US` already matches `en-US-POSIX`, then the weight of `en-US` is the relevant thing for deciding where to put that result. The presence of `en-US-POSIX` in your list of requested tags is a red herring.